# How to understand BR and IMG tags?

Tags: html

We know that `p`, `body` and `html` elements have [start tag](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/syntax.html#start-tags) and [end tag](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/syntax.html#syntax-end-tag).

What `<br>` or `<img>` really mean?

Comment: MDN counts BR as start tag: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/br

Comment: If you're already looking up the specs on MDN (which is a great resource for that), what exactly are you asking?

Comment: @David MDN was silent about void elements https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/syntax.html#void-elements

Comment: @user894319twitter --> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Void_element -- They are pretty clear about void elements.  There is a reasonable expectation that asking a question here should be the last resort, not the first thing one does.  SO is not a code "manual" or "tutorial" .. It's a place to discuss specific nuances that are original or unique problems (hence the duplicate question flag) -- I fear the ideal of what this place is, or should be, is getting muddied up with expectation that one doesn't have to do any work before showing up and asking a question.

Comment: [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users)

Comment: @Zak br and img articles don't have a word even in 2024.

Comment: @Zak standard is still quiet about void elements under https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/text-level-semantics.html#the-br-element and elsewhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are known as `self closing` tags, although the official name is `void tags`. This means they can't have content, or in other words: they can't have child elements. That is why often `<br />` is used instead of `<br>`, or even `<br></br>` (the latter is invalid because it *could* incorrectly suggest that content would be possible, but it is illegal and meaningless to do so).

Official spec: https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/syntax.html#void-elements

Comment: Current `HTML` spec explicitly avoids end tag for `br` element: https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/text-level-semantics.html#the-br-element

Answer (score 0):

1. Void elements: `area`, `base`, `br`, `col`, `embed`, `hr`, `img`, `input`, `link`, `meta`, `param`, `source`, `track`, `wbr`
2. *Void elements* only have a **start tag**

https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/syntax.html#elements-2